# extract items from several ordered dictionaries stored in one dict object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a parent dictionary here that is a collection of two dictionaries `X` and `Y`. Stored them by using the `DictReader` of the csv module.

Lets call this dictionary `example_dicto` that contains two ordered dictionaries. For clarification, from the variable explorer in Spyder this looks like:

```
Name         Type  Size  Value
example_dict dict  2     {'X':OrderedDict, 'Y': OrderedDict}
```

Ok, so I know `X` and `Y` are the main keys here. But I would like to look up values through these two dictionaries. Suppose there is a `Duration` column for `X` and `Duration (min)` for `Y` and I would like my function to read over these columns depending on a row and return their values.

```
def info_from_row(row, dictionary):
    if dict == 'X':
       duration = float(row['Duration'])
    else:
       duration = float(row['Duration (min)'])
    return duration
```

When I call `info_from_row`, python returns the usual KeyError where the traceback is telling me that none of these 'keys' exist.
So basically I have to index a dictionary that is a collection of dictionaries and then index keys within their 'main' keys X and Y to return a value. How do I index them since the usual `dict['key']` method is giving me an error and besides `'Duration' in X` returns `False`.

For more clarification, these dictionaries look like the following:

```
print(example_dict)

{'X': OrderedDict([('ID', '123456'), ('Duration', '54941')]), 
 'Y': OrderedDict([('ID', '789101'), ('Duration (min)', '7869')])}
```

Comment: how are you calling this function? What arguments are you passing to it?

Comment: I'm getting doubts on the grammar of calling this function too. Simple `info_from_row(5, 'X')` is giving me that error. That is return the value for the   5th value of the `Duration` column of `X`.

Comment: ``example_dict['X']['Duration']`` returns ``'54941'`` alright. If you're calling ``info_from_row(example_dict, 'X')``, then ``row['Duration']`` is actually ``exampld_dict['Duration']``, which is indeed a ``KeyError``. You should use something like ``row[dict]['Duration']`` and ``row[dict]['Duration (min)']``. (Also, don't call variables ``dict``, it's a Python builtin...).

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do here, but don't name your function argument `dict`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have corrected it accordingly. In my real function, the argument is not `dict` actually, its just a reference I'm using here. But I've corrected the above content to be more clear.

Comment: @Shiv_90 You seem to have a poor understanding of how `dict`ionaries (and `OrderedDict`s) work. Do some reading on that. what are you expecting the `5['Duration']` to return? `5` is the `row` you are passing

Comment: I see. Let me edit some of my code again. Your answer works but I have to extract according to rows. The real dictionaries `X` and `Y` have over 6000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are quite confused as to what it is you want to do and how to achieve it. Assuming I understood your question correctly, this is how I would do it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def info_from_row(my_dict):
    try:
        return float(my_dict['Duration'])
    except KeyError:
        return float(my_dict['Duration (min)'])

example_dict = {'X': OrderedDict([('ID', '123456'), ('Duration', '54941')]),  
                'Y': OrderedDict([('ID', '789101'), ('Duration (min)', '7869')])}

print(info_from_row(example_dict['X'])) # -> 54941.0
print(info_from_row(example_dict['Y'])) # -> 7869.0
```

As you can see, the duration is printed regardless of which **subdictionary** you wish to query.

---

Another way to do the exact same thing that does not use `try`-`except` is this:

```
def info_from_row(my_dict):
    if 'Duration' in my_dict:
        return float(my_dict['Duration'])
    else:
        return float(my_dict['Duration (min)'])
```

which has exactly the same outcome and is called in the exact same way; `info_from_row(example_dict['Y'])`.

---

If you want the main `key` (`'X'` or `'Y'`) to be a function-argument as well, you can slightly modify the function (any of them) like so:

```
def info_from_row(my_dict, main_key):
    if 'Duration' in my_dict[main_key]:
        return float(my_dict[main_key]['Duration'])
    else:
        return float(my_dict[main_key]['Duration (min)'])
```

but then the call statements have to be modified as well:

```
print(info_from_row(example_dict, 'X')) # -> 54941.0
print(info_from_row(example_dict, 'Y')) # -> 7869.0
```

Comment: Yea, surely I'm somewhat confused since this is actually the first time in my beginner python experience that I'm seeing dictionaries with dictionaries :P